# Proper wording for purchase button on mixed service/product acquisition process

Tags: e-commerce, wording, purchase

I need to create a button that will actually finish a purchase process. Like **"Buy Now"** , or **"Create Membership"**, or simply **"Submit"** *(eeeew!)*

Now, my problem is that in this process you won't actually buy a product. Instead, a professional will visit the user. This professional will also bring (or not) a set of tools, with a price difference. User chooses whether to tell the professional to bring these tools or provide them on their own.

Of course, I already thought of the classic options for this kind of scenarios like **"make appointment"** or **"hire service"** or similar, but I don't feel they're correct, because you're not making an appointment and you're not only hiring a service, but you MIGHT be actually purchasing the set of tools (tests provided by clients show this will happen in around 70% of cases)

## In short

How can I label this *purchase button* in a more accurate way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem with the more obvious solutions like "Hire Service" and "Make Appointment" is the descriptor words. Consider more ambiguous language that still lets the user know this finalizes the 'booking' or 'hiring'. If you need to maintain more professional language I would consider:

- **Finalize**
- **Reserve**
- **Book**
- **Create**

Depending on your brand image you could try some colloquial language like these *(keep in mind the associations that may come with phrases like these)*:

- **Make It Happen**
- **Let's Do It**
- **Bring It On**

Answer (score 1):

I would use "Complete order". 
Would also create couple of other versions, and A/B tested them with Optimizely service.

Answer (score 0):

> ...my problem is that in this process you won't actually buy a product. Instead, a professional will visit the user.

Assuming the user has had to perform a process to reach this point of "purchase", the logic arrival point is "*get it*", "*get it now*", "*get it here*"...

[image]